# VB.net - ToString.Contains not recognising strings in Datatable

Tags: vb.net

after finding many useful answers on this site from others' questions I am now in a position where I need to ask my own question as can't seem to find a similar issue elsewhere...

I am working on a Windows Form project in VB.net.  I have many text boxes which require data validation.  Therefore, I am storing the limits for the text box values in a seperate xml file and the below code runs on the validating event of each text box.  This has worked fine up until now....

I have tried to include more text boxes and subsequently edited the xml file (importing to MS Access then exporting back to overwrite the original xml file).  Now, when debugging, I see the updated datatable has been loaded/read correctly from the xml but the ToString.Contains returns False when it should return True.  Its as if the string is not being recognised correctly in the Datatable.  I really can't think what is causing this as it was working perfectly well before trying to add more text boxes.  Any help would be very gratefully received?!!

```
    For Each row As DataRow In data.dtLimits.Rows
        If row(1).ToString.Contains(tb.Name) Then
            ul = Double.Parse(row(2).ToString)
            ll = Double.Parse(row(3).ToString)

            If IsNumeric(tb.Text) Then
                If Double.TryParse(tb.Text, value) Then
                    If value > ul Or value < ll Then
                        e.Cancel = True
                        tb.Select(0, tb.Text.Length)
                        ErrorProvider1.SetError(tb, "Please enter a value between " & row(3).ToString & " And " & row(2).ToString)
                    End If
                End If
            ElseIf tb.Text = "" Then
                tb.Text = 0
                e.Cancel = False
            Else
                e.Cancel = True
                tb.Select(0, tb.Text.Length)
                ErrorProvider1.SetError(tb, "Please enter a valid datum")
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

NB- The data table has four columns 0-ID Value, 1-Textbox Name,2-Upper Limit,3-Lower Limit.

Comment: When you step thru the code, `row(1).ToString` does contain `tb.Name` and the casing is the same also?

Comment: Are you iterating all the rows in the datatable each time you validate a single textbox? Maybe use a keyed data structure such as a Dictionary<String, classWithUpperAndLower> with the textbox names as keys.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  @Chase Rocker- Yes, when I step through I can view the data in row(1) in VS which appears to match that of tb.name (on the corresponding iteration,obviously)

Comment: @Verdolino - Thanks, using a dictionary is probably a better way of doing it.  I will give it a go and see if it works.